# Will leaving an electric hose faucet timer in direct sunlight damage the timer?

Tags: outdoor, hose, timer

I recently bought an electronic outdoor hose faucet timer.  I live in a desert with 110+ degree summers and plan to water a few trees in my lawn with it.  Is there any risk of leaving this device out in the heat?  I would expect it to be designed for it (since it is for outdoor use), but probably for your "average" temperature locations.  I could not find a hard yes or no answer on this when searching online.

My house faces the sun during sunrise and the hose/spout has no shade protection.

The hose timer I purchased is [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-1-Outlet-Hose-Faucet-Timer-56619/205585027).

Comment: Can you provide a brand and model? I would say it should be designed to handle 110 degree heat but extended high heat will shorten the battery life. I have seen electronic controls handle hot temps 120f but do know it shortens the life when there is a hot cold cycle that your timer will be going through but would still expect it to last several years if the batteries are changed prior to leaking.

Comment: @EdBeal I added a link to the one I purchased.  It is Orbit brand.

Comment: It's not the ambient temperature you should worry about, it's the temperature **_inside_** the device caused by the sunlight heating it up.  That'll toast most electronics!

Comment: @steve Wellens the mfg has no way of staying a contact temperature so they provide a ambient temp above freezing and below 120.  Electronics can handle very hot temps the wave solder machine in my department ran at 650F the batteries will fail before the electronics when heat is involved and when that happens they leak. Most batteries are limited to 110f for normal use and start self discharging at 150f  I learned this working on hot presses where the back up batteries for the memory had to be remotely located but the PLC’s were ok.

Comment: @EdBeal   Ambient temperature is fine if the unit is **in the shade**.  But in the sun it will cook...especially because it is black.   I got a device UL approval for Honeywell.  And I could list my degrees.  But I think this is just common sense.

Comment: @steve Wellens and that is the reason I suggested a cover in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions say max working temp of 120f I would probably put a light color cover over it Because that’s not far off 110. A cover may affect the rain delay feature but would reduce the direct sun exposure temp to the ambient temp. also it needs to be kept from freezing .

Comment: Not sure how I missed that in the instructions. Thank you.  Do you have an example of a "light color cover".  Not familiar and I don't think Google is giving me what you mean.  And we can certainly get to 120 where I live, so this would be good to have!!!

Comment: Thanks are great but if this answered your question up voting and or accepting the answer will help others find it.  A light color like white or yellow they reflect light better even a dark color for example if your home is brown a brown cover painted the color of the house can block direct light. I have a light gray hose hanger that has a door large enough for a different brand but the same type of device it fits inside and is out of view this idea may Also work for you. Mine is very similar to a product named suncast cast deluxe hose hangout.

Comment: I usually wait ~24 hours or at least give it an evening before accepting.  Plus I was waiting to get more info about the cover you mentioned (whether there was something specific to this product, or if it was something to buy, or DIY.  Thank you again.